# Passport got wet in snowfall but not damaged - can it still be used for a new visa?

Tags: visas, passports

Four years ago in Saint Petersburg, my passport got wet but not damaged.

There is no damage on the pages, they just got slightly wrinkled.
I had a business visa after that incident and travelled back to my country and again with the same visa I travelled to and from Russia a couple times.

I am planning to apply for new visa; do you think I should apply with same passport?

Answer (score 2):

I infer from your silence that no-one made any comment about your passport when you travelled with it after getting it wet. I had a passport which got wet due to heavy rain in South America. Half of a US transit stamp was lost, along with the gilt lettering and coat of arms on the front cover. When I travelled back through the US one official inspected my passport and told me I should take more care of myself (sic). At the border of my own country the passport officer said he would admit me "*this* time" (his emphasis). But I was still able to use the passport for a journey to the Middle East before I got a replacement.

Therefore if your passport hasn't attracted any comment in a few trips, I would not be concerned about it. It can be worse and still usable.

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't be a problem as long as your passport is still **valid and for a period of more than 6 months**, and the **pages are legible**, especially the pages that contain **import information about your identity**. You also need to ensure that you have **enough pages available for the new visa**, most of this information will be provided to you when you do the visa application.

So it should be fine to apply for the visa with your current passport taking the above into consideration.